# Как сделать красивый ползунок, QSlider?

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, paintevent, qslider

Не понимаю, как сделать вот такой ползунок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы оставался синий след и сам он круглый был.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Пример `qss` стилей по `QSlider` в оф документации](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

P.s (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `Customizing QSlider`)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sld = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider{
                background: #E3DEE2;
            }
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {  
                height: 10px;
                margin: 0px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background: #B0AEB1;
            }
            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #E3DEE2;
                width: 17px;
                margin: -5px 0; 
                border-radius: 8px;
            }
            QSlider::sub-page:qlineargradient {
                background: #3B99FC;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        """)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(sld)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QRect, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QSlider, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QProxyStyle, QStyle, QStyleOptionSlider)


__Author__ = """By: Irony
QQ: 892768447
Email: 892768447@qq.com"""
__Copyright__ = "Copyright (c) 2018 Irony"
__Version__ = "Version 1.0"


class SliderStyle(QProxyStyle):

    def subControlRect(self, control, option, subControl, widget=None):
        rect = super(SliderStyle, self).subControlRect(
                                               control, 
                                               option, 
                                               subControl, 
                                               widget
                                                      )
        if subControl == QStyle.SC_SliderHandle:
            if option.orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                # Высота 1/3
                radius = int(widget.height() / 3)
                offset = int(radius / 3)

                if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
                    x = min(rect.x() - offset, widget.width() - radius)
                    x = x if x >= 0 else 0
                else:
                    radius = offset
                    x = min(rect.x(), widget.width() - radius)

                rect = QRect(x, int((rect.height() - radius) / 2),
                             radius, radius)
            else:
                # Ширина 1/3
                radius = int(widget.width() / 3)
                offset = int(radius / 3)
                if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
                    y = min(rect.y() - offset, widget.height() - radius)
                    y = y if y >= 0 else 0
                else:
                    radius = offset
                    y = min(rect.y(), widget.height() - radius)
                rect = QRect(int((rect.width() - radius) / 2),
                             y, radius, radius)
            return rect
        return rect

class PaintQSlider(QSlider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaintQSlider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Установите прокси-стиль, в основном используемый для расчета и разрешения области щелчка мыши
        self.setStyle(SliderStyle())

    def paintEvent(self, _):
        option = QStyleOptionSlider()
        self.initStyleOption(option)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Положение среднего круга
        rect = self.style().subControlRect(
            QStyle.CC_Slider, option, QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)

        # Картина средних белых линий
        painter.setPen(Qt.white)     
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)   
        if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal:
            y = self.height() / 2
            painter.drawLine(QPointF(0, y), QPointF(self.width(), y))
        else:
            x = self.width() / 2
            painter.drawLine(QPointF(x, 0), QPointF(x, self.height()))

        # Нарисуйте круг
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:             # Двойной круг
            # Полупрозрачный большой круг
            r = rect.height() / 2
            painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 100))
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, r, r)

            # Малый круг (верхнее и нижнее левое и правое смещение 4)
            rect = rect.adjusted(4, 4, -4, -4)
            r = rect.height() / 2
            painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, r, r)

            # Draw текст
            painter.setPen(Qt.white)
            if self.orientation() == Qt.Horizontal:          # Нарисуйте текст сверху
                x, y = rect.x(), rect.y() - rect.height() - 2
            else:  # Нарисуйте текст слева
                x, y = rect.x() - rect.width() - 2, rect.y()
            painter.drawText(
                x, y, rect.width(), rect.height(),
                Qt.AlignCenter, str(self.value())
            )
        else:  # Сплошной круг
            r = rect.height() / 2
            painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, r, r)


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 300)
        self.setTitle("QSlider, нарисовано paintEvent")

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(PaintQSlider(Qt.Vertical,   self, minimumWidth  = 90))
        layout.addWidget(PaintQSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self, minimumHeight = 90))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setStyleSheet('QWidget {background: gray;}')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]